# Typeahead UI not shown when the number record return from the server is equals to the number set in the limit params

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead

I am having [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) jquery plugin to show suggestion items from the server powered by Elasticsearch. Everything works fine except when the server response back to the autocompletion request from the client with the number of records equal to the number I set in the limit (10), the plugin stop working by showing nothing if it were no result was returned.

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead(
  {
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 0,
  },
  {
    name: "products",
    limit: 10,
    source: autoCompleter
  }
);
```

After checking the network request tab in the dev tools I saw the server did return the result but when the number of results is the same as the number of limits I set in the plugin, the plugin simply shows nothing.

I can confirm this if I set the **limit** attribute to a lower number, for example, **limit: 5** while the number of records still returns with 10 items then the plugin worked just fine. I also tried a few other numbers as well.

Is there anybody having this problem and how to overcome it?

Comment: ha, have exactly the same issue!